# Android App rejected due to Violation of Permissions policy

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I am not sure how to proceed.

I have submitted an app that has a feature which allows user to 'Send Invites' via SMS (from within the app) which requires that I include the following permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

A day after I submitted my app I received the following rejection notice:

```
Publishing status: Rejected
After review, your app has been rejected and wasn't published due to a policy violation. 
If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still available on Google Play.

Issue: Violation of Permissions policy
After reviewing your app, we found that it doesn’t qualify to use the requested permissions 
for the following reason(s):

    • Requested permissions do not match core functionality of the app
    You declared Default SMS handler (and any other core functionality usage while 
    default handler) as the core functionality of your app. However, after review, 
    we found that your app does not match the declared use case(s). Learn more 
    about permitted uses and exceptions.

    Please either:
    • Make changes to your app so that it meets the requirements of the declared core functionality or,
    • Select a use case that matches your app’s functionality
```

Can anyone assist me on how to move forward?! Does this mean I need to remove the feature that lets users 'Send Invites' to their friends?

Any assistance is appreciated!

Comment: If for inviting a new user, you are only sharing a normal web/deep links to download/open the app then sms permission is not required. A simple implicit intent would work just fine.

Comment: Hello @DarShan so , in my case the user clicks the button to share and it transitions to the SMS intent which has both pre-set verbiage and the app link in the playstore. If I understand correctly, i will NOT need to get permission to send that SMS?

Comment: If its just the Intent you are using (with added links & texts) then No, you don't need the SMS permission.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/default-handlers

Basically, to allow an app to use the `SEND_SMS` permission, it has to act as the *default handler* for SMS functionality for the whole device - it has to replace the basic SMS app, and provide all the functionality you'd expect. Some exceptions are listed [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10208820#zippy=%2Cexceptions), and you can use the permissions without needing to be the default handler if one of those cases applies to you.

These permissions are a privacy and security concern, which is why their use is restricted and limited to a few specific situations, or apps where the user expects it to have that level of access (like an actual SMS app).

For most applications, the typical way of doing things like this is with an `Intent` - have a look around for some tutorials on this (I haven't actually done it so I can't make any recommendations!) and maybe look into the `SmsManager` class too (again, never used it, might be helpful or might be completely unsuitable!)